# How to querying a db in php with for loop without heavy load?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am building a website for online exam , when user choose a particular exam
then subjects for is fetched from database.Then number of subjects is counted and then assigned to a variable $no_of_sub.
Each subject has sub categories stored in a variable $subject_cat[][].

```
$no_of_sub=7;//Here i assigned the no.of subject directly
$subject_cat= array ( array('Indian History','Indian national movement'),
                      array('Indian and World Geography',' Indian Geography',
                            'World Geography','Geography(jammu and kashmir)' ), 
                      array('Indian Constitution','Indian Political History'), 
                      array('Economic and Social Development',
                            'Sustainable Development',' Poverty',
                            ' Inclusion', 'Demographics',
                            ' Social Sector  initiatives'), 
                      array('Environmental Ecology', 
                            'Bio-diversity and Climate Change','Physics ',
                            'Chemistry ','Biology','General Science'), 
                      array('Defence Technology','Space Technology',
                            'Nuclear Technology','Biotechnology','Health',
                            'Other Technologies'),
                      array('Current events'),    
                      array('General knowledge') );

        //$subject_cat is a multi dimension array having sub categories for each subjects

for($i=0; $i<$no_of_sub; $i++)
//loop for subjects till no of subjects
{
    for($j=0; $j<count($subject_cat[$i]); $j++)
       //loop for each sub category within a subjects using multi dimensional array  $subject_cat[subjects][sub_cat]
    {


        //Determine which subject to display the questions for
        $query = "SELECT ques_id, q, op1, op2, op3, op4
                  FROM questions where cat='".$subject_cat[$i][$j]."' limit 3";
        //for each subject category , it fetches data from MYSQL database Ex: where 

        cat="science"....
       //
       // other code goes here
       //
```

My problem when running my code in local host , it does not fetching all category but only for one category

```
Where is the Indus Civilization city Lothal ? a) Gujarat b) Rajasthan c) Haryana d) Punjab

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum
execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
C:\wamp\www\loginregister-master\testpage.php on line 68
```

My question is how to prevent this problem, i want to optimize my code because
each time when fetching data it took long time because my table has more than 3000 rows for each category.So the php execution time takes longer.
even i limited the query to 1 , the query has not any changes.
i just want to select 1 question from every category and process in shorter time.
Anyone who help me will be appreciated.

Comment: build one query and join the tables.. so you only have one query, and one loop.

Comment: try to use one sql statement to retrieve the information for all categories.

Comment: Each exam has different amount of questions ,according to user choice exam has different types of questions which is queried from db.

Comment: all the questions are in one table @Rufinus

Comment: Why are you not using the 'Subject Id' - the first line of your question, in the sql query? I assume that the 'subject id' is part of the unique index of (subjectId, category, question). at which point the query will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
for loop requires more execution time and also the data cache capacity of server become increased due to data fetch in each cycle
hence now i use
separate function.It works perfectly now without any problem.